# How can I make an ordered relation with values optional in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

My car object has four passenger objects. The car needs to know where the passengers are sitting, but the reverse relations wouldn't make sense, i.e. `frontPassengerSeatOccupant` would be logical, but `carWhosFrontPassengerSeatImSittingIn` seems pointless (then I'd need three others for the other three seats), and I'd rather just have one `carImSittingIn`.

CoreData is recommending that I have inverse relationships for everything except in "advanced" cases, so I'm trying to abide by that. So I'm trying to do an ordered `occupants` relation, where seat 0 is driver, 1 is front passenger, 2 is rear driver, 3 is rear passenger. The problem occurs when I don't have anybody in seat 1, but i have somebody in seat 2 or 3, because I can't put a placeholder in the array.

What would be a clean way to implement this ordered, possibly empty seat problem while maintaining inverse relationships, and not having all these extra pointless properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways you could do this: provide an object that represents an unoccupied seat, or create an intermediate `Seat` object that contains the participants.

Core Data models ordered relationships as an `NSOrderedSet`. `NSOrderedSet` stores objects contiguously (i.e. it won't contain any `nil` values) You could create a dummy object that represents an unoccupied seat. You'd need to track the "null occupant" object, and I imagine you'd end up with a lot of complicated `if ([occupant isNullOccupant])` logic to deal with this special case.

The other solution, which I think is cleaner, is to have three entities: `Car`, `Seat`, and `Occupant`. A car would have a to-many relationship with `Seat`, and a `Seat` would have a to-one relationship with `Occupant`. Your model would look like this:

```
Car <-->> Seat <<--> Occupant
```

Comment: I think the seat option is the fastest solution for me, it prevents extra code to look up the order, while also preventing me having to create a lot of dummy occupant objects.

Answer (score 2):

Just have the Occupants object contain a seatNumber property (you can use an integer as in your thoughts above) which you set for each occupant.

Then you could have 1-4 Occupant objects in your ordered set with no "empty" spots being used just as placeholders.

I would then have a method in your Car object something along the lines of:

```
- (BOOL)addOccupant:(Occupant *)occupant {
    // Make sure that occupant.seatNumber is valid.
    // Check your existing occupants to make sure nobody is already in that seat.
    // Add them to the relationship (your ordered set) in the proper order.
}
```

Comment: +1 for using a seat number attribute on the occupant. I wouldn't bother with ordering the relationship, which is extra work with no semantic value (unless it actually means something in your app). You can always sort the occupants by seat number. If it's important to check whether the occupants are in distinct seats, keep in mind that the seat number could change after the occupant is added to the car. You might want to implement validation on the car object instead of checking in `-addOccupant:`

Comment: +1 I like this option, but it isn't ideal for me due to speed, I've simplified the problem and the real code needs to deal with chains of seats within seats recursively, so I'm gunning for the fastest lightest solution

Comment: @noa I figure that one sort when you add the object is simpler (and faster, and less error prone) than sorting it every time that you access the array...

Comment: @AlexGosselin: this is very fast, especially compared to creating extra objects.  The recursive problem changes things though.  (how do you have recursive seats in a car anyway??  :) )

Comment: @Inafziger I used a car to explain, but really the four items are four quarters of a map, and those quarters are further divided into four, repeatedly until I reach the smallest division. It's a kind of binary lookup in space, where the tree only expands to add parts of the  map as they are visited.